# 503 service unavailable when debugging PHP script in Zend Studio

Tags: apache-2.2, debugging, 503-error

I have a web server with apache 2.0 installed. It comes with Zend Server install pack. When I’m trying to debug my php files apache serves a blank page with 503 service unavailable. Of course slow server-side code is tying up Apache requests for far too long, but I need it to wait, until my debugging comes to end.

When I call to the page from a browser it launches ZendStudio debugging my PHP script (request redirects Zend Debugger module). I debug through my script and if I finish debugging in 120 seconds, I normally return to the browser. When it takes more than 120 seconds the browser displays '503 service unavailable' and I can't return to page output. I have even forced 'max_execution_time = 300' 'max_input_time = 600' in php.ini and 'TimeOut = 500' in httpd.conf. No matter whether it is Opera, IE or Firefox. I spent two days googling it, no right answer until now.

Answer (score 1):

I found some additional information on this for Zend Studio 6/7.  Go into Preferences -> PHP -> Debug -> Installed Debuggers -> Zend Debug -> Configure.  Specify the Client Host / IP to the IP of your computer.  In my case, the problem was that it was configured to send Zend Server a list of IP addresses, which then caused Zend Server to lag as it attempted to communicate with each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to set the TimeOut directive?: [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout)

Comment: 'TimeOut = 500' in httpd.conf - if you read the question carefully, no matter

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the file called ZendEnablerConf.xml. You'll find the 120 seconds timeout there.

Comment: After you have edited ZendEnablerConf.xml file and saved it please don't forget to restart your Apache server (Zend Server) and restart Zend Studio or Eclipse as well...

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Zend config files at `C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\etc` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\etc` for 64-bit